# Create drivers for virtual com ports in windows using c++

Tags: c++, windows-10, drivers, virtual-serial-port

My goal is to create serial connection between two remote computers. The message that I want to send from a virtual serial port will be redirected to a portal using the TCP protocol. Then the portal sends the received message and redirects it to the other pc's serial port. 
For this I tested and I want to simulate the program [Serial to Ethernet Connector](https://www.eltima.com/products/serial-over-ethernet/) using c++. This program allow me to create client connection that will initiate local real or virtual serial port data redirection to the remote server using TCP/IP protocol. The client **must run on a Windows OS**. For now I created a simply TCP Client using QT and I can send QString to the server (the portal) but that I want is write some strings from a hyper terminal (such as Putty) that is open in the virtual serial port (COMx) **that I have to create**.
The server is created by this socat command:

```
socat -d -d pty,link=/dev/ttyS0,raw,echo=0 tcp-listen:1234
```

So I can forward the strings that I recived to the serial port **/dev/ttyS0** that is in the Fedora OS.
Now, for create a virtual serial port, I searched on the web and I found the [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) function.
With this function I wrote, in QT, this code:

```
#include <windows.h>

HANDLE driver = CreateFileA("\\.\COM15", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, CREATE_NEW, 0, 0);
driver = CreateFileA("\\.\COM15",  GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
if(driver == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    qDebug() << GetLastError();
    CloseHandle(driver);
    return;
}
else
{
    qDebug("Open");
    qdebug() << driver;
    return;
}
```

If I go in the device management (in Windows 10), I don't find the new device COM15 under the section Ports (COM and LPT). Why?
The function that I used is not correct?
What function I should use for create a driver that allow me to create a virtual com port using c++?

Comment: You are trying to create a driver? It's not gonna work like that, you have to implement `DriverEntry()`, then to create a device, etc. It's a quite complex topic, you have to decide what kind of driver you want to make, more on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/).

Comment: You are doing this the wrong way around.  CreateFile cannot create a new device.  It must be the driver that creates the device first, then you can use CreateFile to open it.  That for one means that you must never hard-code the port name, you need config to allow the user to select it.

Comment: `CreateFile` does not create a serial port. Please be more specific and try do describe your task, sounds a little bit like XY problem to me.

Comment: @vasek I have to simulate the program [Serial to Ethernet Connector](https://www.eltima.com/en/products/serial-over-ethernet/) using c++.
This program allow me to create client connection that will initiate local real or virtual serial port data redirection to the remote server using TCP/IP protocol. 
The server is created by this socat command: `socat -d -d pty,link=/dev/ttyS0,raw,echo=0 tcp-listen:1234`
Is it clear now?

Comment: @JacopoGardin not much, still it is unclear whether the serial port really exists in your OS. Is it physically present in your PC or do you have any FT232 USB convertor that creates COMx device when connected? Also please kindly edit your question with clarifications, don't use comments for that.

Comment: @vasek, I want to create a virtual serial port so I don't have to use things like FT232 USB convertor...
I edited the question so I hope to be clearer.

Comment: @JacopoGardin then you need to follow comments above. Note that's quite complex task.